# Regression on dataset whose scatter plot contains 2 clusters

Tags: r, regression, time-series, data-transformation, python

I'm new to regression and I am trying to perform regression analysis on two time series `Price A` (x-variable) and `Price B` (y-variable). When doing LASSO regression, the R-squared score is extremely low at 0.01. Log transformations made it worse.

Plotting out the scatter plot, we can see 2 different clusters. How should we handle such a data set? And how do we interpret such a scatter plot?

```
plt.scatter(df['priceA'], df['priceB'])
plt.xlabel('Price A')
plt.ylabel('Price B')
```

[image]

Comment: Your "Price B" series includes a lot of negative values. How are "prices" *negative*?

Comment: @Glen_b It's a market where prices can become negative when the supply is too high.

Comment: So we're dealing with an important missing variable, *supply*, which would presumably explain the "clumping"?

Comment: @Glen_b I do have the *demand* variable, and used it in a multivariate regression, but R2 were in the range of 0.01-0.02. Should I separate the prices into 2 clusters and regress on them separately?

Comment: Sorry, I can't possibly give you advice like that because I don't understand the situation

Comment: Perhaps a better fit for the economics SE.